# unable to connect through SSH key to bluemix container

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am currently trying to use the bluemix container service (in beta)

When I want to create a new container, I follow the steps, and just choose the name and the ports to open. I paste a SSH, and at the end I get the error :
*"Unable to create container. Error message returned is: Bad Request"*.

Whereas if I do not paste my key, there is no problem.

I have tried with another key, created with puttygen, and I still get the same error.

I don't know what is wrong, as I basically chose the default options.

I have tried with the browsers firefox & opera on windows.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you copying the contents of your public ssh key into that box? What are you using to copy the contents (an editor or putty)?

Comment: I am using the windows "bloc notes" in French, it must be scratchpad or something like that in English, the basic tool to get pure text. And I have just tried with notepad++, it gives the same error. The text is utf-8 w/o BOM, and of type UNIX, if this can be useful. And yes, I am copy/pasting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a public key of the form "ssh-rsa", space, 200+ characters ending in ==, space, username@hostname.  I generated mine using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.  I pasted the entire contents of the generated .pub file.

Comment: Thank you, it was a problem with spaces in the key. I had to erase the ===SSH2 PUBLIC KEY=== at the beginning and the end of the key. I had to be very careful, because with one space more or less, I got an error